# How to display product price on custom meta filed woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display product price on single page custom field. That filed is only readable filed users cant option to edit that price. Also on variable product page when product variations change according to that price also need to change. I have added below code for display the the custom field on single product page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field() {
   // global $product;

    echo "test";
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">';

    echo  ' <input type="text" name="my_field_name">';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I want to add variations product price on that filed.

Answer (score 0):

To get Product price without woocommerce hook
define product as global
global $product;
and then get product price

```
$product->get_price();

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field() {
   global $product;
   $price = $product->get_price();

    echo "test";
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">';

    echo  ' <input type="text" name="my_field_name" value=".$price.">';
    echo '</div>';
}
```